# MultiSelect Tag how to enter only 1 item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use MultiSelect Tag , please tell me how to make it possible to select only 1 item and block the select.
And another question is how to pass a value to the select via js
Thanks a lot

```
if (document.querySelector('.select')){
    new MultiSelectTag('country')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here you just need to add an object after 'country' parameter like this

```
new MultiSelectTag('country', {singleSelect: true});
```

I guess this will do the job!